# Limit total returned entries - problem

Tags: playa, low-seg2cat

We are having a problem limiting entries correctly.  Our original code:

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="daily-deals" search:monday-deal="not IS_EMPTY" parse="inward" orderby="random"}
    {if monday-deal}
    {exp:playa:children field="deal-owner" category="{segment_1_category_id}" status="Super Enhanced|Enhanced|Basic" parse="inward"}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="daily-deals"}{monday-deal}{/exp:playa:parents} - {title} - {city},{state-short}<br>
    {/exp:playa:children}
    {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

The code above correctly returns the correct entry results (21 total entries) BUT we want to limit the number of results shown.

When we add limit="6" to the outer entry call as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="daily-deals" search:monday-deal="not IS_EMPTY" parse="inward" orderby="random" limit="6"}
{if monday-deal}
{exp:playa:children field="deal-owner" category="{segment_1_category_id}" status="Super Enhanced|Enhanced|Basic" parse="inward"}
{exp:playa:parents channel="daily-deals"}{if monday-deal}{monday-deal}{/if}{/exp:playa:parents} - {title} - {city},{state-short}<br>
{/exp:playa:children}
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

THIS code returns random number of results from 2-6.  I believe it is because when the outter call starts by limiting to 6 entries - not all of those 6 entries make it past the inner calls - thus a different number of results are displayed.

HOW do we return all 21 results, but only display 6 of the total results?

Comment: i think the playa:parents tag also supports the search:field="value" parameter (skip a conditional). and what fieldtype is ```{monday-deal}```? And is daily-deals self related (parents tag on same channel?)

Comment: look at the template debugger and at the queries this is generating. You can try those queries in SequelPro / phpMyAdmin to see what is happening.

Comment: We are getting the correct results, it is just not limiting correctly.  We have updated our question and used cleaner code (and tried to identify the problem clearer) here:  [http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9616/problems-limiting-within-an-embed]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but you could try wrapping your template code inside the channel entries with this:

```
{if count <=6}

{/if}
```

Theoretically this should only display the first 6 results that match what you get.

Comment: +1 for going by the original question (how do we limit the output to 6 entries).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is directly associated with your problem but just something I notice looking at your code is that you seem to duplicate a lot of the conditional checks. If you're using `search:monday-deal="not IS_EMPTY` then you don't need a conditional check for `{if monday-deal}` as you've already checked is has something in it.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="daily-deals" search:monday-deal="not IS_EMPTY" orderby="random" limit="6"}

        {exp:playa:children field="deal-owner" category="{segment_1_category_id}" status="Super Enhanced|Enhanced|Basic"}

            {exp:playa:parents channel="daily-deals"}
                {monday-deal}
            {/exp:playa:parents} - {title} - {city},{state-short}<br>

        {/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I've also stripped out the other conditional around {monday-deal} later on, but I'm not entirely sure, that one may be required. Try it and see.

I've also removed the `parse="inward"` tags as I'm not sure you need those either? What do you get with the above?

Comment: You are correct - there were a few redundant checks - however the issue is:

Comment: `[STEP 1] {exp:channel:entries channel="daily-deals" search:monday-deal="not IS_EMPTY" orderby="random" limit="6"}
[STEP 2]    {exp:playa:children field="deal-owner" [STEP 3] category="{segment_1_category_id}" status="Super Enhanced|Enhanced|Basic"}
[STEP 4]    {exp:playa:parents channel="daily-deals"}{monday-deal}{/exp:playa:parents} – [STEP 5] {title} - {city},{state-short}<br>
    {/exp:playa:children}
  {/exp:channel:entries}`

Comment: The ISSUE is the number of results that are returned and output in the template.

Step 1 – Identifies all the deals that have Monday populated and limits to 6.  [Selects ALL the deals that have something in the Monday field and then selects 6 random entries]
Step 2 - Looks to the “deal-owner” field and finds the businesses associated with all the identified deals (the children of the 6 deals)

Comment: Step 3 – Of the businesses identified in Step 2, selects those that have the matching zone to the template name (using category=”{segment_1_category_id}”)  for instance the business is classified in the zone: Rapid City (url=rapid-city) and the template is www.website.com/rapid-city/deal-test
Step 4 - Then displays the deal information
Step 5 – And displays the business title, city and state to display within the output template.

Comment: **The problem is that the limit function only works in step 1, but if we put the limit there, Steps 2, 3, 4 and 5 only work with the initially selected 6 random entries – thus when the records are checked against step 3, some are dropped off – resulting in the display of less than 6 entries.

Comment: Have you tried moving the limit parameter from the channel entries tag to the Playa Children tag? This tag supports all of the regular Channel Entries tags including the limit parameter.

Comment: Yes we have - and in this construct, the "limit" tag does not work in either the children or the parent tag. (it still displays the 21 entries)

Comment: We took another approach that may help identify the problem a little clearer here:  [http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9616/problems-limiting-within-an-embed]